# Infering type of an abstract class

Tags: typescript

I have a bit of a convoluted case, I'm 99% sure it's impossible to solve in typescript, and the issue very clearly comes from connecting Typescript code with unsafe JS code. But I've seen miracles preformed on this site before...

I have some JS code, which I can't control but I must use, that takes an automatically generated abstract class (from protobuf definition, but it doesn't matter) extends and creates it. The automatically generated classes have `d.ts` files attached, which is the important part, as I want to keep their type information for autocomplete purposes.

So, let's start by wrapping the JS code that extends and creates the abstract classes ->

```js
type getCtorType<Ctor> = Ctor extends { new(): infer T } ? T : never;

const initalizeClass = <Ctor extends { new(): any }>(abstractCtor: Ctor): getCtorType<Ctor> => {
    return null as any; //In reality, here there is a call to javascript code that does all the magic
}
```

so let's say I have two classes for example sake, one is abstract the other isn't:

```
class Foo {
    someFunc(a: string) {}
}

abstract class Bar {
    someFunc(a: string) { };
}
```

and we initalize them:

```
//This has type inference;
const instance1 = initalizeClass(Foo);
//This is an error
const instance2 = initalizeClass(Bar);
```

The second line fails, because an abstract class does not satisfy the constraint of `{ new (): any}` as it cannot be created.

If I remove this constraint from `initalizeClass` and use something like  `Function` instead,

```
const initalizeClassAlternative = (abstractCtor: Function) => {
    return null as any; //In reality, here there is a call to javascript code that does all the magic
}
```

**If I do this, I lose all type inference.**

Can anyone think of a way/trick to extract the type out of an abstract class passed to a function? in a similar way to how it's possible to extract the type of a regular class?

---

If you are wondering why something like this isn't good enough and I really want type inference:

```
const instance2: Bar = initalizeClassAlternative(Bar);
```

Here is a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20someFunc(a%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20someFunc(a%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20getCtorType%3CCtor%3E%20%3D%20Ctor%20extends%20%7B%20new()%3A%20infer%20T%20%7D%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst%20initalizeClass%20%3D%20%3CCtor%20extends%20%7B%20new()%3A%20any%20%7D%3E(abstractCtor%3A%20Ctor)%3A%20getCtorType%3CCtor%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%20%2F%2FIn%20reality%2C%20here%20there%20is%20a%20call%20to%20javascript%20code%20which%20I%20can't%20control%20that%20does%20all%20the%20magic%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20instance1%20%3D%20initalizeClass(Foo)%3B%0Aconst%20instance2%20%3D%20initalizeClass(Bar)%3B%0A%0A%0A%2F%2FPART2%3A%0A%0Atype%20CtorMap%20%3D%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20%20%7B%20new()%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%0Atype%20InstanceMap%3CT%20extends%20CtorMap%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20getCtorType%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20map%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20service1%3A%20Foo%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20generateInstanceMap%3CT%20extends%20CtorMap%3E(ctorMap%3A%20T)%3A%20InstanceMap%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%20%2F%2Fhere%20we%20will%20call%20initalizeClass%2C%20doesn't%20matter%20right%20now%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2Fthis%20works%20great%0Aconst%20instanceMap%20%3D%20generateInstanceMap(map)%3B%0AinstanceMap.service1.someFunc('foo')%3B%20%2F%2Fwe%20have%20autocomplete%20on%20this%20line%0A%0A%0A%0Aconst%20mapWithAbstractServices%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20service2%3A%20Bar%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2Fthis%20fails.%0Aconst%20instanceMap2%20%3D%20generateInstanceMap(mapWithAbstractServices)%3B%0A%2F%2FI%20aim%20that%20the%20next%20line%20will%20have%20autocomplete%0AinstanceMap2.service2.someFunc('')%3B). The example there is closer to my real use case, since this question is already too long I cut it out... But in short I'm trying to use mapped types.

Comment: Your use-case doesn't make sense. `abstract` means that the `class` will never be constructed directly, yet you're trying to imply with your declaration that it _is_ used as a constructor directly. That's why it's an error.

Comment: By the way, the implementation could look something like [this](https://gist.github.com/patrickroberts/cbbb87c1c0ae8f517c718cb9806bacff)

Comment: I was going to type up an answer but I’m stuck on mobile.  Try doing a lookup on the prototype property like `Ctor['prototype']`.

Comment: @jcalz this is great! feel free to add an answer when you can and I'll gladly accept it. and again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before there was [type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types), there were [lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).  According to [the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L298), the `Function` interface has a `prototype` property of type `any`.  Classes (even abstract classes) will override this property with a type corresponding to the instance type of the class in question.  So, as a quick workaround for your issue, you can examine this property:

```
type InstanceType<Ctor> = Ctor extends Function ? Ctor['prototype'] : never;
```

(I changed the name from `getCtorType<>` to `InstanceType<>` for aesthetic reasons you may not care about, so feel free to change it back.)
This lets you use your second approach:

```
declare const initalizeClass: <Ctor extends Function>(
    abstractCtor: Ctor
) => InstanceType<Ctor>;

abstract class Bar {
    someFunc(a: string) { };
}

const bar = initalizeClass(Bar);
bar.someFunc("works");
```

Looks good to me!  There are further possible refinements if you want to exclude passing non-`class`-like `Function` types to `InstanceType` (e.g., require that the `prototype` property not be `any`), but they are probably not necessary.

Hope that helps; good luck!